# different font sizes and justifications on a single line

Tags: css

I need to put two small pieces of text on a single line. The two pieces should be left-  and right-justified, respectively. Here - http://jsfiddle.net/smithfarm/xa6jc0wm/ - is a nice way to accomplish that:

```
<div id="textbox">
<p class="alignleft">left</p>
<p class="alignright">right</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.alignright {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This is fine, but I also need one of those pieces to have a different font size *and* I need both pieces to be vertically aligned to the bottom of the "text box". However, when I change the font size, the pieces become vertically aligned to the top: http://jsfiddle.net/smithfarm/ucgs6s7c/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: try adding `line-height` http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ucgs6s7c/2/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes: thanks for the effort, but the two pieces of text in your fiddle are not bottom-aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Inline-block Solution

instead of float you can use `display:inline-block` property and control the vertical.alignement of the p elements.

Since inline-block produce a little extra space between elements you have to set the font-size of the parent to 0 and then give a different size for the children...

```
#textbox{
    font-size:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#textbox *{font-size:1rem;}
.alignleft {
    text-align:left;
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.alignright {
    text-align:right;
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucgs6s7c/8/) with that css

Comment: This works - thank you. It does make me wonder, though: shouldn't the two texts be bottom-aligned by default without having to do sleight-of-hand with font sizes?

Comment: the two texts ARE bottom-aligned due to the vertical-align property of the parent element. but two inline-block with 50% width can't be on the same line because of the little space between them... the font-size:0 hack is a simple way to avoid this behaviour... here's a link with a detailed explanation of various methods to remove that space http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Yes yes, I know they are bottom-aligned in your fiddle. When I said they weren't (in the comment above), I was referring to Vitorino's fiddle, not yours. Thanks for the link!